# Example buildspec.yml for browserstack-sdk

Tags: aws-codepipeline, browserstack, pyobjc

When following the [browserstack guidance for AWS CodePipeline](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/aws-codepipeline) integration a requirement is that a `buildspec.yml` file is available.

Does anyone have an example `buildspec.yml` that successfully uses browserstack-sdk with Python on an AWS linux-flavoured instance?

My attempt failed on the package `pyobjc-core` which apparently can only be built on Mac OS [ref](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).